# Which language's syntax highlighting does .vimrc use?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

My .vimrc looks nice and syntax-highlighted:

[image: vimrc syntax highlighting]

I'd like to have the same style of syntax highlighting for my own file which is *not* called `.vimrc`.

What would I have to name my file so it gets the right syntax highlighting or, alternatively, which language's syntax highlighting is being used, so I can select it manually?

Comment: When using TextWrangler, `lua` seems to be good enough for my syntax highlighting needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filetype (as in what vim internally refers to as filetype) is 'vim'.  You should be able to use any extension, really.  Putting something along these lines into your .vimrc might work.

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.yourextension set filetype=vim
```

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that if you try to set an option without specifying a value, vim will tell you the _current_ value. So when editing `.vimrc` you could type `:set ft` to have vim tell you the type. This doesn't desrve its own answer, but I think is useful and related.